# Thymeleaf switch block returns incorrect value

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a switch block in my thymeleaf page where I show an image depending on the reputation score of the user:

```
<h1>
    <span th:text="#{user.reputation} + ${reputation}">Reputation</span>
</h1>
<div th:if="${reputation lt 0}">
    <img th:src="@{/css/img/troll.png}"/>
</div>
<div th:if="${reputation} == 0">
    <img th:src="@{/css/img/smeagol.jpg}"/>
</div>
<div th:if="${reputation gt 0} and ${reputation le 5}">
    <img th:src="@{/css/img/samwise.png}"/>
</div>
<div th:if="${reputation gt 5} and ${reputation le 15}">
    <img th:src="@{/css/img/frodo.png}"/>
</div>
<div th:if="${reputation gt 15}">
    <img th:src="@{/css/img/gandalf.jpg}"/>
</div>
```

This statement always returns smeagol (so reputation 0), eventhough the reputation of this user is 7: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmR0Q.jpg)

**EDIT:**

I was wrong, the image showing was a rogue line:

```
<!--<img th:src="@{/css/img/smeagol.jpg}"/>-->
```

but I commented it out. Now there is no image showing.

**EDIT2:**

changed my comparators (see original post) and now I get the following error:

```
 The value of attribute "th:case" associated with an element type "div" must not contain the '<' character.
```

**EDIT3:**

Works now, updated original post to working code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#switch-statements), Thymeleaf's `switch` statement works just like Java's - and the example suggests the same.

In other words: you cannot do

```
<th:block th:switch="${reputation}">
    <div th:case="${reputation} < 0">
[...]
```

but would need to do

```
<th:block th:switch="${reputation}">
    <div th:case="0">
[...]
```

which is not what you want.

Instead, you will have to use [`th:if`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#simple-conditionals-if-and-unless), i.e. something like this:

```
<div th:if="${reputation} < 0">
    <img  th:src="@{/css/img/troll.png}"/>
</div>
```

Comment: It's still giving me the following error: 
The value of attribute "th:if" associated with an element type "div" must not contain the '<' character.

Comment: Got it ! the correct way is : <div th:if="${reputation lt 0}"> Thank you for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Great, glad you found the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
  <div th:case="0">
    <img  th:src="@{/css/img/smeagol.jpg}"/>
  </div>
```

to

```
  <div th:case="${reputation == 0}">
    <img  th:src="@{/css/img/smeagol.jpg}"/>
   </div>
```

Comment: That still shows smeagol, and it should be showing the image of frodo in this case, since the reputation is 7.

Comment: @Audiosleef check your other compactor is work fine or not

Comment: what do you mean the other compactor?

Comment: @Audiosleef such as `gt` `lt`

Comment: changed them to le, as is stated in the thymeleaf documentation https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standarddialect5minutes.html and now an error occurs. I've modified my original question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172842/discussion-between-audiosleef-and-lucumt).